# Cannot start node missing module

Tags: node.js, docker

I am new to node so using this as a starting point.

https://github.com/voduytuan/docker-socketio

APP.JS

```
var http = require('http');
var socketio = require('socket.io');

var app = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var postData = "";
    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
      postData += chunk; //Get the POST data
    });

    req.on('end', function() {
      if (typeof(postData) !== "undefined") {
        var message = JSON.parse(postData);

        //Do something here
        //Todo...
      }
    });
    res.end();
}).listen(8080);  //Use a non-standard port so it doesn't override your Apache

var io = socketio.listen(app); //Attach socket.io to port 8080

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {

  });
});
```

DOCKER RUN:

```
docker run -ti -d --restart=always --name mysocketio -v app.js:/srv/app.js -p 8080:8080 voduytuan/docker-socketio
```

DOCKERFILE:

```
FROM zzrot/alpine-node
MAINTAINER Vo Duy Tuan <tuanmaster2012@gmail.com>

RUN apk add --update \
    supervisor \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

ADD supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

RUN /bin/mkdir -p /srv/logs

WORKDIR /srv


RUN npm install --silent socket.io@0.9.14
RUN npm dedupe

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]
```

DIR:

Dockerfile
License
Readme.md
supervisord.conf
app.js

When I look at the log files I see this?

```
Error: Cannot find module '/srv/app.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:352:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:144:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:467:3
```

Comment: check the spelling  i think it may be src/app.js

Comment: dockerfile sets as srv

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `app.js` in your Docker container.

To add it, modify the `Dockerfile` and add an `ADD` command:

```
FROM zzrot/alpine-node
MAINTAINER Vo Duy Tuan <tuanmaster2012@gmail.com>

RUN apk add --update \
    supervisor \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

ADD supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

##### CHANGE HERE:
ADD app.js /srv/
#####

RUN /bin/mkdir -p /srv/logs

WORKDIR /srv


RUN npm install --silent socket.io@0.9.14
RUN npm dedupe

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]
```

Comment: Did you re-build the image?

Comment: yes. docker stop mysocketio, docker rm mysocketio, docker system prune -a

Comment: Try a `docker build -t voduytuan/docker-socketio .`

Comment: this worked. I build it and then run it separately.

Answer (score 1):

Copy you current directory to /srv:  **COPY . /srv**
Assuming your folder structure looks like this in the same folder:

> |--Dockerfile
>
> |--app.js
>
> |--supervisord.conf

```
FROM zzrot/alpine-node
MAINTAINER Vo Duy Tuan <tuanmaster2012@gmail.com>

RUN apk add --update \
    supervisor \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

ADD supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

RUN /bin/mkdir -p /srv/logs

WORKDIR /srv

COPY . /srv

RUN npm install --silent socket.io@0.9.14
RUN npm dedupe

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]
```

Comment: Still same issue. Error: Cannot find module '/srv/app.js'